# How can I open a .NET core 2.0 mvc project despite that I have .NET core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a .NET Core 2.2 MVC project, running these commands:

```
dotnet new mvc -n Test
```

Then, I changed this line in Test.csproj

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

However, when I run "dotnet build", it gave me error like this:

> error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to downgrade the NuGet packages as well..

Comment: How can I downgrade NuGet packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this commands,

```
 dotnet --list-sdks
```

List your sdk's, then uninstall all of these versions, except 2.0:

For example for OS x, it's like

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.103
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/2.2.103
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.103
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.103
```

Then, run

```
dotnet new mvc -n Test
```

In conclusion, if you have .NET core 2.2, you cannot open any 2.0 projects. You need to uninstall them.

However, as a shortcut, you can use this template. Replace these in your csproj.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You only need to change `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` to `2.0.3`. For .NET Core sdk, it could be installed side by side, there is no need to unintall other .net core version.